# file_put_contents не хочет создавать файл

Tags: php, cron, openserver

Столкнулся с проблемой на локальном OpenServer, в корне проекта создаю папку `cron` в неё кладу файл `update.php` c вызовом функции.

```
<?php
file_put_contents($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/cron/'.date('H:i:s-d-m-Y').'.txt', "123");
```

Что по сути должно создавать txt файл, обзывать его датой, и писать туда 123, в соответствии с документацией. [file_put_contents](https://php.ru/manual/function.file-put-contents.html)  После вызова данного файла `http://test.loc/cron/update.php` получаю ошибку

`Warning: file_put_contents(D:/OpenServer/OpenServer/domains/test.loc/cron/13:25:24-15-11-2022.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\OpenServer\OpenServer\domains\test.loc\cron\update.php on line 12` 
и файл он не создает, подскажите в чём может быть проблема?

*Вижу, что слеши не в ту сторону, но это же, не в этом проблема? На других форумах пишут что доступ к папке должен быть `777` или `775` но ведь я на локалке стартую, и оно уже тут не работает(

Comment: а что там насчет двоеточия в названиях файлов в виндах?

Comment: Не понимаю о каких двоеточиях речь? Если в `data()` то это без разницы, уже как только файл не обзывал.

Comment: а пробовали руками файл с таким названием создавать?

Comment: Да, вы оказались правы. Это было из-за неразрешенного символа `:`